# python Query parameters for receiving post

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Here I am having a problem which is as follows:
I 'm getting parameters via post to make querys depending on paramtros I are passed ... doing gender filters.
So I'm doing well

```
def filter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        namepost = request.POST.get('name')
        surnamepost = request.POST.get('surname')

        if namepost != None and surnamepost != None:
            result = [a.get_json() for a in Player.objects.filter((Q(name=namepost) & Q(surname=surnamepost)))]
       elif namepost != None and surnamepost == None:
            result = [a.get_json() for a in Player.objects.filter(name=namepost)]

        data = {"meta": {"total_count":len(result)}, "objects": result}
        aa = json.dumps(data)
        return HttpResponse(aa, content_type='application/json')
```

Is working properly , the problem is :
If it were only these two parameters , there was no problem , was to complete the rest of the hypotheses ... the problem is that I can have up to 10 parameters passed by post to the filters , and I never know which are passed , can be 1 , 2, 4, ... as the user makes the filter

But doing so would take a lot of ifs , it would have many chances ...
is there any way I can do this another way ?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, and assuming I've understood your question correctly, you could do something like this,

```
def filter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        filter_objects = [
            Q(**{key: value}) for key, value in request.POST.iteritems() if value
        ]

        result = [a.get_json() for a in Player.objects.filter(*filter_objects)]

        data = {"meta": {"total_count":len(result)}, "objects": result}
        aa = json.dumps(data)
        return HttpResponse(aa, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: I managed to do ... so I did: http://plnkr.co/edit/L1ByIyFyaEdgwrfVU7Jr?p=info But I have a problem that is, but this works for direct filter fields as name and surname, but not for the position because to do for the position had to do something like this:Player.objects.filter(position__in=Position.objects.filter(name=positionpost))
How can I do this in code? Someone can help me?